# C# How to get top window title and process name

Tags: c#, .net

Lets assume there are two win applications with name ABC and XYZ. XYZ application always stays on top of the screen but ABC application is in behind the XYZ application and it is focused, now how to get top of the screen(XYZ).i am always getting focused window with the below method.

```
 [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();
```

Is there any way to get top of the window details even it is not in focused.

Comment: You need to use `GetWindowInfo` and you need a handle to the window that's not focused. `GetForegroundWindow` always returns focused window

Comment: To get a handle to not focused window you need either a window name and use `FindWindow` WINAPI function or you could try in C# using `Process.GetProcessesByName` to get process by name and then use `MainWindowHandle`